# A Very Sharp Cosmological Constant Problem In a 1+1 Dimensional Universe?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, vacuum, cosmological-constant

Equations of GR with a cosmological constant $\Lambda$ read

$R_{{\mu}{\nu}}-\dfrac{1}{2}Rg_{{\mu}{\nu}} + \Lambda g_{{\mu}{\nu}} =8\pi T_{{\mu}{\nu}}$

Therefore,

$R-\dfrac{D}{2}R+D\Lambda=8\pi T$

($D$ is the number of spacetime dimensions.)

Or,

$\Lambda = \dfrac{8\pi T}{D} + \bigg(\dfrac{D-2}{2D}\bigg)R$

Therefore,

$\Lambda = \bigg(\dfrac{D-2}{2D}\bigg)R_0$ 
where $R_0 := R_{vacuum}$

Therefore, for $D=2$, $\Lambda=0$.

So, a universe with $1+1$ dimensions can't have a non-zero cosmological constant. Now, would the quantum fields in such a universe have a positive zero-point energy? If yes then the cosmological constant should be expected to be positive. If so then the cosmological constant problem appears to be extraordinarily sharp and of the form of a theoretical paradox--because we have got the value of the cosmological constant to be positive from a theoretical argument (the one related to the zero-point energy of quantum fields) and we have also got a vanishing cosmological constant from the theory (GR) in a straightforward manner. Whereas in the 3+1 universe, the problem is about a disagreement between the theoretical prediction and the experiment--in particular, GR in itself predicts no value of the cosmological constant in $3+1$ but it seems to do so in $1+1$.

The only crucial assumption (as far as I can see) in my argument is that the quantum fields would give positive zero-point energy in a 1+1 universe--this, sadly, I can't verify owing to my limited knowledge of QFT. I am posting this question, of course, to find out if my argument really poses a paradox.

Comment: For $D\ne 2,\,\Lambda=0$, taking traces gives $(1-\frac{D}{2})R=8\pi T$, so in general $T\ne 0$. For $D=2$ you've come to the conclusion $T=0$ by assuming $T$ contributes to an effective Ricci scalar as if $D\ne 2$, but here this seems to be a division-by-zero error. Instead we expect $\Lambda =4\pi T$.

Comment: @J.G. No, I don't assume that $T$ contributes to an effective Ricci scalar. What I am doing is I am evaluating $\Lambda$ at a point in spacetime where there is vacuum - thus, $T=0$ at that point - giving the relation $\Lambda = \dfrac{D-2}{2D}R_{vacuum}$.

Comment: In 2D Einstein tensor is identically zero. 2D gravity is obtainable from Brans-Dicke for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9310041

Comment: @Kosm But does it resolve the problem that if quantum fields would produce positive zero-point energy then there would be cosmological constant problem?

Comment: @Dvij C.C. doesn't have to vanish there, so yes, I suppose

Comment: @Kosm Ok. I looked at the paper now. It basically says that GR shouldn't be used for 2D. And then proposes a different theory. But I am not completely convinced that GR is completely out of the window for 2D. I will have to think. Is it the general scientific consent that GR doesn't work in 2D?

Comment: @Dvij Of course. Einstein-Hilbert action in 2D is topological invariant, the Euler number of the space. So its variation vanishes identically.